# Oracle timestamp, timezone and utc

Tags: sql, oracle, apache-flex, timezone, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an application, using an Oracle 11g (11.2.0.2.0 64 bit) db.

I have a lot of entries in a Person table. To access data I'm using different application (same data).
In this example I'm using birth_time field of my person table. 
Some application queries data with birth_time directly, some other with to_char to reformat it, and some other with UTC function.

The problem is this: with same data, same query, result are different.

In this screenshot you can see the result with **Oracle Sql developer (3.2.20.09)**

[image: Query with Sql developer]

All the timestamp are inserted with midnight timestamp, and in fact the to_char(..) and birth_time result are at midnight. UTC hours are returned with one hour less (Correct according to my timezone!) but some entry (here one for example, the last one) is **TWO HOURS less** (only few on thousand are Three)!!

The same query executed with **sql*plus** return the correct result with one hour of difference for all the entries!

Does anyone have a suggestion to approach this problem?

The issue is born because one of our application made with adobe flex seems to execute queries with UTC time, and the problems appears when you look at data with this component.

ps.:
"BIRTH_TIME" is  TIMESTAMP (6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible for you to change the query used? If so, you could use the `AT TIME ZONE` expression to tell Oracle that this date is in `UTC` time zone:

```
SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CAST(TRUNC(SYSDATE) AS TIMESTAMP)) AS val FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
VAL                        
----------------------------
13/11/20 23:00:00,000000000
```

Now, using `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` gets you the date you need:

```
SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(
          CAST(
            TRUNC(SYSDATE) AS TIMESTAMP)
          AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS val FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
VAL                        
----------------------------
13/11/21 00:00:00,000000000
```

Comment: select internal_id, birth_time, SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CAST(TRUNC(birth_time) AS TIMESTAMP)  AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin' ), 
to_char(birth_time,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') from person where name_giv = 
'MILENA' and name_fam like 'C%';

return me the same error above, the last date in my resulset has the  wrong hour.

Comment: @Francesco Yes, because you specified the `'Europe/Berlin'` time zone - refer to my example, you have to use the `'UTC'` time zone.

Comment: thanks. It worked. I was confused on the meaning of "at time zone xxx" . I need to do some more work aroud my app, but this could work.
I'm still surprised why the same query, gives different result on sql*plus and sql developer :S

Comment: @Francesco It gives different results because the session settings matter. You can check and compare the parameters by issuing `SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters;` in SQLPlus and SQLDeveloper.